# Problema com RAND no SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou usando o MySQL "5.6.38-log - MySQL Community Server (GPL)"

Tenho uma procedure que é executada a cada segundo, e nela tem uma validação com um RAND:

```
WHERE t.auc_due_time < GREATEST(LEAST(TRUNCATE(12 * RAND(),0),12),2)
```

O problema que estou enfrentando é que ele ta sempre executando a query em 5 OU 7 nesse rand, eu preciso que ele fique alternando sempre, por exemplo 11,9,3,5,2,7,10,11 etc..

Por que será que não ta funcionando dessa forma? Existe alguma outra forma de fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

Conforme a documentação do MySql, a função [RAND([N])](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand), retorn um ponto flutuante entre 0 e 1.0. Para obter um número randomico inteiro R sendo i <= R < j, você precisa da seguinte expressão

```
FLOOR(i + RAND() * (j − i))
```

Por exemplo, para obiter um randomico inteiro entre 7 e 12, use o seguinte código (7 <= R < 12)

```
SELECT FLOOR(7 + (RAND() * 5));
```

Um inteiro entre 0 e 100 ficaria o seguinte:

```
SELECT FLOOR(0 + (RAND() * 100));
```

ou

```
SELECT FLOOR((RAND() * 100));
```

Para um randômico de 2 a 12, tens que fazer o seguinte:

```
SELECT FLOOR(2 + (RAND() * 11));
```

Veja a execução do exemplo no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d7c5dc/3)

Comment: No caso seria dessa forma para um intervalo de 2 a 12? `WHERE t.auc_due_time < FLOOR(2 + (RAND() * 10));`

Comment: É isso ai mesmo.

Comment: Pois é eu fiz dessa forma mas parece naõ funcionar também, ele ta pegando até o 7.. Só para esclarecer melhor, ele fica rodando junto com um cronometro regressivo de 15 segundos, ai preciso que ele execute a query nos segundos de 2 a 12 alternando sempre...

Comment: Eu fiz uma edição na minha resposta

Comment: obrigado pela resposta.. E como seria para fazer entre 1 e 12?

Comment: seria só colocar `SELECT FLOOR(1 + (RAND() * 11));`

Comment: Como posso alterar esse comando para que ele gere os números aleatoriamente e que o número 1 apareça com mais frequência?